# Drive letters switched after restoring from backup

Tags: windows-xp, backup

I have a drive image made in Acronis of an XP machine. The original computer has a C:/ drive, an E:/ partition, and a CD drive on D:/. When I restore from the backup, the E and D drive letters are switched. How can I prevent this from happening?

I suspect it has to do with the MBR, but beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that the second partition will be detected before the CD drive, so therefore gets priority with the Drive letter.

Comment: I neglected to mention that it had been working previously for quite a long time. Something happened to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `diskpart`, you can probably use

```
list volume
select volume N
assign letter=E
```

(where N is the number of your partition you want to be E:, found via the output of `list volume`)

Since the hard drive volumes get priority over the CD drive, as you suppose, this'll cause C: and E: to be allocated, so the CD drive gets D:.

Good luck!

Comment: Only had the opportunity to test it right now. I ended up setting the CD drive to F. Thank you.